# I need help drawing a Hand of Cards

Tags: java

I am trying to draw a Hand of Cards (in the Hand class) but have it shuffled. My problem is if I do shuffleDeck() in the initialDeal() method (where I need to draw a Hand of Cards but shuffled) it gives me an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception.

And I draw two narfs OF Clubs...  Note, the narf is basically 0 and just a placeholder. It will not be used.

```
class Card {    
int suit, rank;   
public Card () {    
    this.suit = 0; this.rank = 0;   
}       
public Card (int suit, int rank) { 
    this.suit = suit; this.rank = rank;   
}      
public int getSuit() {   
    return suit;   
}       
public int getRank() {  
    return rank; 
}       
public void printCard () { 
    String[] suits = { "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades" };    
    String[] ranks = { "narf", "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6",  
    "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King" }; 
    System.out.println (ranks[rank] + " of " + suits[suit]); 
} //end printCard
} //end class
```

Card class(this is basically doing basic stuff) ^

```
import java.util.Random;
class Hand {
static Card[] deck = new Card[52];
Card[] hand = new Card[10];
static int index;

public static void createDeck () {
    int m = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        for (int k = 1; k < 14; k++) {
            deck[m] = new Card(j,k);
            m++;
        }
    }
    index = 0;
} // end createDeck

public static Card deal () {
    Hand.index++;
    return deck[index-1];
} // end deal

public static int compareCard (Card c1, Card c2) {
    if (c1.getSuit() > c2.getSuit()) return 1;
    if (c1.getSuit() < c2.getSuit()) return -1;
    if (c1.getRank() > c2.getRank()) return 1;
    if (c1.getRank() < c2.getRank()) return -1;
    return 0;
} // end compareCard

public void printDeck (int size) {
    int j = 0;
    while (j < size) {
        deck[j].printCard();
        j++;
    }
}// end printDeck

public static void shuffleDeck () {
    Card tempCard;
    Random rd = new Random();
    for (index = 0; index < deck.length; index++) {
        int r = rd.nextInt(deck.length);
        tempCard = deck[index];
        deck[index] = deck[r];
        deck[r] = tempCard;
    }
} // end shuffleDeck

public void initialDeal() {
    hand[0] = null;
    hand[1] = null;

    hand[0] = deal();
    hand[1] = deal();
}


public void printHand() {
    initialDeal();
    index = 0;
    for(Card outputCard = new Card();  hand[index] != null;  index++) {
        outputCard.printCard();
    }
}    
}
```

Hand class^ (this is where I need to draw two cards from a shuffled deck)

```
class Dealer {    
Hand dealer = new Hand();    
public Dealer () {      
    dealer.createDeck();  
    dealer.shuffleDeck();

    System.out.println("Dealer's Hand");
    System.out.println("");
    initDeal();
}

public void initDeal() {
    dealer.initialDeal();
    dealer.printHand();
}
} //end class
```

Dealer class.^ Calling the methods of Hand

```
class Driver {     
     public static void main (String[] args) {  
         Dealer dealer = new Dealer(); 
     } //end main method 
} //end class
```

^ Running everything basically

Comment: Please narrow this down yourself, the exception tells you exactly where the problem is occurring.

Comment: I have no exception being thrown anymore.

Comment: Time to learn how to use a debugger.  It's an important skill so it's worth the investment.  http://www.eclipse.org/resources/resource.php?id=405

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're modifying the `index` in `shuffleDeck`, so after the `shuffleDeck` finishes, the `index` is `shuffleDeck.length`.

In `shuffleDeck`, do `for (int index = 0; index < deck.length; index++)`

(note the `int index` -> declare local variable, and not use the static one.)

Or you can (in `initialDeal`) set the index to 0.

Comment: I realize that I should shuffle the deck in the Dealer class so I updated it.
I still get the same problem so far though.

Comment: in that case, use debugger. Look at on which line the exception is thrown, and what is the index and array you're accessing. And try to think about 'why the index is out of bounds'.

Comment: I do not have that exception happening anymore for the reason I do not/ did not incorporate the shuffleDeck() method in the  initialDeal() method. 
I just can't seem to though have any card otherwise drawn except for the narf of clubs which tells me that it is not shuffling. 
I did the shuffle in the Dealer class to try shuffling but it did not work.